# obtaining radius and distance from

Tags: multivariable-calculus

A bicycle wheel has radius R. Let P be a point on the spoke of a wheel at a distance d from the center of the wheel. The wheel begins to roll to the right along the the x-axis. The curve traced out by P is given by the following parametric equations:

$x = 16\theta-10sin\theta$
$y = 16 - 10cos(\theta)$

what must we have for R and D

Answer (score 0):

Yours is a *curtate* cycloid.

Read D.H.von Seggern *Practical Handbook of Curve Design and Generation* (1994), p.61 (figure p.62) searching in books.google.com .